# How to automatically insert `\bigstrut` for first and last rows in `nicematrix`?

Tags: math-mode, nicematrix

When using `bNiceArray` from `nicematrix` along with vertical rules in the columns preamble, we see that they slightly exceed the brackets from top and bottom. One solution is to add `\bigstrut[t]` and `\bigstrut[b]` at the top and bottom lines. Is it possible to achieve the same thing by `nicematrix` itself and get it to insert such struts for the first and last rows?

[image]

My MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{bigstrut}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=b}
    $\begin{bNiceArray}{ccc|c}[margin]
        \Block[]{3-3}<\large>{Z} &               &   &   0    \\
                                 & \hspace*{1cm} &   & \Vdots \\
                                 &               &   &   0    \\ \hline
                   0             &    \Cdots     & 0 &   0
    \end{bNiceArray}$
\end{adjustbox}
\quad
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=b}
    $\begin{bNiceArray}{ccc|c}[margin]
        \Block[]{3-3}<\large>{Z} &               &   & 0 \bigstrut[t] \\
                                 & \hspace*{1cm} &   &     \Vdots     \\
                                 &               &   &       0        \\ \hline
                   0             &    \Cdots     & 0 & 0 \bigstrut[b]
    \end{bNiceArray}$
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new environment `{bNiceArray*}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment { bNiceArray* } {O { } m O { } }
  { 
    \begin { bNiceArray } [ #1 ] { #2 } [ #3 ]
    \bigstrut[t]
  }
  { 
    \bigstrut[b]
    \end { bNiceArray } 
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceArray}{ccc|c}[margin]
    \Block[]{3-3}<\large>{Z} &               &   & 0              \\
                             & \hspace*{1cm} &   &     \Vdots     \\
                             &               &   &       0        \\ \hline
               0             &    \Cdots     & 0 & 0 
\end{bNiceArray}$
%
%
$\begin{bNiceArray*}{ccc|c}[margin]
    \Block[]{3-3}<\large>{Z} &               &   & 0              \\
                             & \hspace*{1cm} &   &     \Vdots     \\
                             &               &   &       0        \\ \hline
               0             &    \Cdots     & 0 & 0 
\end{bNiceArray*}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]